# Return FILE pointer from function and work on it on main

Tags: c, file, pointers

I've tried to return a `FILE` pointer from some function to `main()`.
After it, I've tried to do some `fprintf` on the pointer but it wasn't working.
Here is my code:

My function:

```
FILE *create_file(void){

    FILE *regularTxt = NULL;
    regularTxt = fopen("MyLogExamplekkggggggk.txt", "wt");
    if (!regularTxt){
        printf("error with regtxt");
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }
    char first_part_string[] = "kkkkik";
    fprintf(regularTxt, "%s\n\n\n%s", "ttttg", "lklf");
    return regularTxt;
}
```

The `main` function:

```
int main(void)
{
    p_txt = create_file();
    fprintf(p_txt, "%s\n\n\n%s", "gggg", "lklf");
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

> Error 92  error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'p_txt' used

Comment: Have you used a debugger to check the value of p_text before you try to `fprintf` to it?

Comment: You should probably factor the file name out so that there's a variable which you can then use in both the call to `fopen()` and in the error message.  You should report the error on standard error.  Be very cautious about having a function like this use `getchar()`.  Make sure you return a NULL pointer on error, not the value `1` coerced to a `FILE *`.  You could combine the definition and open in one line: `FILE *regularTxt = fopen(filename, "wt");` — the compiler optimizes away your initialization to NULL followed by assignment, but…  You don't use `first_part_string`, so why define it?

Comment: FWIW, `clang` gives me a warning instead of an error, and I believe its message to shed more light on the issue: `warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'int' from a function with result type 'FILE *' (aka 'struct __sFILE *') [-Wint-conversion]: return 1;`

Answer (score 2):

Without all the code I can't explain the warning, but when you "return 1" from the function in the error case you didn't initialize the pointer correctly.

Change to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *create_file()
{
    FILE *regularTxt = NULL;
    regularTxt = fopen("MyLogExamplekkggggggk.txt", "wt");
    if (regularTxt) {
        char first_part_string[] = "kkkkik";
        fprintf(regularTxt, "%s\n\n\n%s", "ttttg", "lklf");
        return regularTxt;
    }
    return NULL; // error
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE* p_txt = create_file();
    if (p_txt == NULL)
    {
        printf("error with file");
        getchar();
        exit(1); // quit
    }
    fprintf(p_txt, "%s\n\n\n%s", "gggg", "lklf");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `nullptr` is C++, not C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Correct, fixed.  (Habit)

Comment: Interestingly, in `create_file()`, you could move the `return regularTxt;` out of the `if` statement and use it in place of the `return NULL;` — simply return its value, NULL or not, but don't use it unless it is non-null.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - True but my goal was to transform the code as directly from the original as possible to make it easier to follow for OP.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be treating warnings as errors here. I think you should first check the returned value for `NULL` to silence this error:

```
FILE *p_txt = create_file();

if (! p_txt) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] Failed to open the file!\n");
    return 1;
} else {
    fprintf(p_txt, "%s\n\n\n%s", "gggg", "lklf");
}
```

Also, when you're entering into `if (!regularTxt)`, you're returning one from a function returning a pointer. Better return `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The below works, replace 1 with NULL to remove the compiler warning shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *get(){
  FILE *myfile = fopen("fio.txt", "wt");
  if(1 == 2){
    return 1;// this causes a warning, setting this to NULL removes the warning
  }
  return myfile;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  FILE *fp = get();
  fprintf(fp, "hi there C\n");
}
```

fio.c:6:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'int' from a function with result type 'FILE *' (aka 'struct __sFILE *') [-Wint-conversion]
    return 1;
           ^
1 warning generated.

Comment: What's with the `1 == 2` comparison?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was becase the compailer feared when i didnt initialized the value of the pointer to NULL...thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Solved that adding a CAST in the function's call.
I.E.: In this example, replaced this:

```
p_txt = create_file();
```

With this:

```
p_txt = (FILE *) create_file();
```

Hope It helps!